# Dagger is null at SplashActivity

Tags: android, dagger-2, dagger

I use **Dagger** in my app.
As the documentation says, I instatiate it at my `Application` class as a `private` `static` class member, and get it by a `getter` where I need it.

```
    private void initDagger() {
    appComponent = DaggerAppComponent
            .builder()
            .appModule(new AppModule(this))
            .build();
}
```

But sometimes when call the `getter` from my `SplashActivity` (this is my Launcher `Activity`) `appcomponent` is null, so I get a `NullpointerException` when I try to inject `SplashActivity` into Dagger.
I can't reproduce this issue, but I can it in Crashlytics.
It maybe happens if the user doesn't close the app, but returns after a long time. In this case I call `SplashActivity` again and clear the stack, because I have to reinit some things I can do just here. Maybe that's the point when the `appcomponent` will be null.
I can see this issue in just `SplashActivity` and on just Android 7.x (and some 6.x).
Now I try to get `appcomponent` like a singletone

```
    public static AppComponent initDaggerAndGet(IndexApplication application){
    if(appComponent == null){
        synchronized (lock){
            if(appComponent==null)appComponent = DaggerAppComponent
                    .builder()
                    .appModule(new AppModule(application))
                    .build();
        }
    }
    return appComponent;
}
```

when I get it at the `SplashActivity` and I refactor `initDagger()` method like this

```
    private void initDagger() {
    initDaggerAndGet(this);
}
```

As I wrote, I can't reproduce the issue, and I can't find something like this issue at SO.
What do you think what can be the problem? Will the refactored initalization solve it?
Thanks!

Comment: Please include _all_ of the relevant code that is affected as well as the error and the actual stack trace. My guess would be that the activity was destroyed and recreated, and you don't recreate the component for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

finally I was able to reproduce the issue.
I started my app, than a lot of other still my app was killed. At this time if I started my app from task manager or by the launcher icon, I get this exception. The private static instance of Appcomponent in my Application class was null.
So now I refactored my AppComponent getter, I get it like as a singletone like this

```
    public static AppComponent getAppComponent() {
    Logger.logAppComponent("");
    if (appComponent == null) {
        Logger.logAppComponent("AppComponent is null");
        synchronized (lock) {
            if (appComponent == null) {
                Logger.logAppComponent("Create still null, so create new AppComponent");
                appComponent = DaggerAppComponent
                        .builder()
                        .appModule(new AppModule(getApplication()))
                        .build();
            }
        }
    }
    Logger.logAppComponent("Return AppComponent");
    return appComponent;
}
```

rather than init AppComponent in Appliaciton's onCreate(), and now it works.